# Two mount points of my partition

Tags: btrfs, mountpoint

I freshly set up Ubuntu, and formatted the whole disk with the btrfs file system. When I look at the mount point in gparted, `/dev/sda5` is mounted both at `/` and `/home`. Is this a problem?

This did not occur before - /dev/sdaN was just mounted at `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used btrfs while installing, then a btrfs subvolume is created for `/home` ([usually named `@home`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs)). See [Btrfs subvolumes vs folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119014/btrfs-subvolumes-vs-folders) for more about subvolumes. It shouldn't be a problem, subvolumes are a nice feature of btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created extended partition. This can hold multiple logical partitions. If so, then all is OK.

For clarification: [What does the term "Extended Partition" mean? Is it safe to use this type of partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par)